# How to detect Active Setup in MSI

Tags: installation, windows-installer

i have a MSI installation package that is installed as SYSTEM User and adds an active setup entry to the registry. This setup makes sure when a new user(new = that has not executed this setup until now) is logging on msiexec adds all missing registry entries.

In the MSIEXEC i need to do a net use to mount the users home directory. This cannot be done as system user and needs to be done in the user context.

However i seem to be completely unable to detect that the setup is currently running on the user context. Thats why i thought it would be nice to give additional parameters to the StubPath in the active setup entry. I tried NETUSE=1. This however did nothing. The setup just ignored this parameter and uses the parameter given during installation. So NETUSE stays 0.

Any ideas what kind of condition i could use for my custom net-use action?

Answer (score 1):

Why is an MSI mounting a users home directory?  I would write a small utility to do all this work and just have the MSI put it in the Run registry key.  Install once per machine as System and then when the user logs in the utility gets called and does whatever per-user work you need to have done.

If the installer legitimately needs to populate per user registry data then that is fine to continue the active setup pattern.

Comment: Why? Because MSI has the theoretical capability to do so. I'd like to have all things that are the Job of this installation, to be a part of this installation. The only thing that hinders the setup seems to be that it never knows exactly what is happening. 

But this run-idea is actually nice. I could create another activesetup entry that does not call msiexec, but net use. Since the home directory mount is managed by samba, the mounting path is for all users the same. So i need no user info for mounting.

Thanks! :)

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that MSI is designed to install shrink wrapped applications.  Mapping network drives isn't an installer concern.  It's an application runtime concern.  You can't just set it once in the installer and forget it.  The application should be checking the status and configuring it as needed throughout the life of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use your own custom action configured to run only when the [LogonUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369780(v=vs.85).aspx) property is different tan SYSTEM.